# In R, what does "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)" mean?

Tags: r, package

In R, what does it mean for a package to be **"loaded via a namespace (and not attached)"** in `sessionInfo()`?

**Edit**:

For example:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

---->>>> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
---->>>> [1] tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Its those packages that are `suggested` by other packages, and are not loaded (to be accessed by the user directly, I should add).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means the package (In this case R) can access the package functions/objects, but the user can not without explicitly loading the tools package where as stats, graphics, etc. are loaded and ready to go for the user.

Here's an example:

```
sessionInfo()
file_ext("file.com")
tools::file_ext("file.com")
sessionInfo()
```

Answer (score 19):

When one evaluates `library(foo)`, R first loads the package foo in to memory, and then attaches the package to the `search()` path. Other operations, such as `loadNamespace("foo")` or `foo::fun`, or when a third party indicates that it imports symbols from foo, load the package but do not attach it to the search path. Since R is a dynamic language, each function call involves a traversal of the available symbols to find the first that matches. It is efficient, and avoids unnecessary name conflicts, by separating the attach and load operations and hence restricting the number of symbols to search.

In the example above, the tools package has been loaded, but not (yet) attached. When one types a symbol at the R command prompt, R looks for the symbol first in the global name space (the first element returned by `search()` and if not found then in successive elements of `search()`. Since tools isn't attached, the symbols in tools are not resolved.

```
> file_ext
Error: object 'file_ext' not found
```

Nonetheless, one has access to them with `tools::file_ext`, whether tools is on the search path or not.

Comment: Is there any diff between loaded name space and unloaded name space, since both can call the function using explicit packagename:function