# MAXENT model in R for Classification

Tags: r, svm, document-classification, maxent

I am trying to Classify text using `RTextTools` package using R.

I have done this using - `SVM` (and the below code works fine :)

```
matrix[[i]] <- create_matrix(trainingdata[[i]][,1], language="english",removeNumbers=FALSE, stemWords=FALSE,weighting=weightTf,minWordLength=3)
container[[i]] <- create_container(matrix[[i]],trainingdata[[i]][,2],trainSize=1:length(trainingdata[[i]][,1]),virgin=FALSE)
models[[i]] <- train_models(container[[i]], algorithms=c("SVM"))
```

But when i do the same thing with `MAXENT` algorithm

```
models[[i]] <- train_models(container[[i]], algorithms=c("MAXENT"))
```

It throws me error:

```
Error in Module(module, mustStart = TRUE) : 
  function 'setCurrentScope' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

When i did traceback - got the below details

```
Module(module, mustStart = TRUE) 
.getModulePointer(x) 
maximumentropy$add_samples 
maximumentropy$add_samples 
train_maxent(feature_matrix, code_vector, l1_regularizer, l2_regularizer,  
maxent(container@training_matrix, as.vector(container@training_codes),  
train_model(container, algorithm, ...) 
train_models(container[[i]], algorithms = c("MAXENT"))
```

**update:**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.5-10        hash_3.0.1       RTextTools_1.4.2 SparseM_1.03    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6       caTools_1.16       class_7.3-9        e1071_1.6-1        glmnet_1.9-5       grid_3.0.2        
 [7] ipred_0.9-3        KernSmooth_2.23-10 lattice_0.20-23    lava_1.2.4         MASS_7.3-29        Matrix_1.1-2      
[13] maxent_1.3.3.1     nnet_7.3-7         parallel_3.0.2     prodlim_1.4.2      randomForest_4.6-7 Rcpp_0.10.6       
[19] rpart_4.1-5        slam_0.1-31        splines_3.0.2      survival_2.37-7    tau_0.0-16         tools_3.0.2       
[25] tree_1.0-34
```

Is there a way to solve this problem.

Comment: can you please post the output of `sessionInfo()`, it most likely is related to missing/dated version of Rcpp

Comment: @Vivek I have update the session information

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but posting here due to longish length of `sessionInfo()`

```
library(RTextTools)
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RTextTools_1.4.1   tau_0.0-15         glmnet_1.9-5       Matrix_1.0-14      lattice_0.20-23    maxent_1.3.3      
 [7] Rcpp_0.10.5        caTools_1.14       ipred_0.9-2        e1071_1.6-1        class_7.3-9        tm_0.5-9.1        
[13] nnet_7.3-7         tree_1.0-34        randomForest_4.6-7 SparseM_1.03      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6       grid_3.0.2         KernSmooth_2.23-10 MASS_7.3-29        parallel_3.0.2     prodlim_1.3.7     
 [7] rpart_4.1-3        slam_0.1-30        splines_3.0.2      survival_2.37-4    tools_3.0.2
```

In my case, all the required modules are loaded under `other attached packages` whereas in your case they are loaded under `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)`

Under case 2, R can access the packages but user cannot. See [In R, what does "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988722/in-r-what-does-loaded-via-a-namespace-and-not-attached-mean) for more explanation

I do not know why the packages are not attached in your case but as a workaround you could try this:

```
#grab list of package names required for RTextTools
# not_attached_list<-dput(names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs))
#c("RTextTools", "tau", "glmnet", "Matrix", "lattice", "maxent", 
#"Rcpp", "caTools", "ipred", "e1071", "class", "tm", "nnet", "tree", 
#"randomForest", "SparseM")

not_attached_list<-c("RTextTools", "tau", "glmnet", "Matrix", "lattice", "maxent", 
"Rcpp", "caTools", "ipred", "e1071", "class", "tm", "nnet", "tree", 
"randomForest", "SparseM")

#Load the packages manually
sapply(not_loaded_list, require, character.only=TRUE)

#Check in sessionInfo if they have been attached now under 'other attached packages'
sessionInfo()
```

let us know if this works..

Comment: If Rcpp is supposed to be available, then the authors of the package should include it in the Imports section of the DESCRIPTION file (which they do not do at the moment.)