# How to import ggplot2 into a new package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, rstudio

I'm creating a new package in R and I'd like to use `ggplot2` as the plotting system. I already declared `ggplot2` in my DESCRIPTION file. There are several functions in `ggplot2` so, although it is not recommended, I'm using `@import ggplot2` to access all of them. However, when I run the code, I get the following message:

> Function `ggplot` could not be found.

Is there a specific way to make use of `ggplot2` when creating a new package?

Comment: @Keon it's a new package. The library() command is [forbidden](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html).

Comment: how did you declare it in the description file. and it's fine to use require/library in your functions for a personal package, but technically it is bad practice

Comment: @rawr I've the following:

Imports:
    ggplot2

The idea is to eventually release this to CRAN, that's why I do not want to use the library function

Comment: imports loads the package but doesnt attach it to the `search()` path, so you still need to `library(ggplot2)`, so like hadley said, if your package is not useful without ggplot2, then you should depend it.. also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988722/in-r-what-does-loaded-via-a-namespace-and-not-attached-mean)

Comment: Is it just me, or did you reference it once as `ggplot` and everywhere as as `ggplot2`?

Comment: @r2evans no, I did it on purpose. ggplot2 is the name of the package, and ggplot is the name of the function is not found.

Comment: Sorry, got it. Of course, I should have seen the word "Function" at the beginning of the error. So much for powers of observation. On further inspection, I have nothing more to contribute over @rawr's *"import loads the package but doesn't attach it ... still need to `library(ggplot2)`"*.

Comment: @rawr thanks for your comment. I move the package to Depends and my code is working.

Comment: @r2evans no worries! Thanks also. I still have a question: what do you mean by 'attach'? And, if I include the package in the Depends section, do I still need to call it with @import?

Comment: In my mind, `Import:` is similar to `install.packages()`: just because it is installed does not mean you can use its functions or data within using `require` or `library`. By `attach`, I think about inserting a package's namespace into the search path. For your question on `@import`, I will redirect you to hadley's [namespace](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) section titled "R functions" where he discusses tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I'll have a look at the link

Comment: Importing usually is preferable to depending. Have you declared ggplot2 under `Imports` in your DESCRIPTION file and do you see `import(ggplot2)` in your NAMESPACE file? If you look at the reverse imports at the [ggplot2 CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) you'll find many packages that do this. No calls to `require`, `library` or `attach` should be necessary when importing correctly.

Comment: @Roland I declared `ggplot2` under `Imports` in my DESCRIPTION file, and then used `@import ggplot2` in the R script. This was not working properly, so I move `ggplot2` to `Depends` in the DESCRIPTION file and it worked. I'm still trying to understand if this is the right way to build a package.